# Copy data from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Is there a way to copy for example one column from MS Access to SQL Server or just a part of the column? I need to copy some rows of one column to SQL Server table just a way I would do this in the MS Excel. There is a great tool for manipulating data for Oracle, named PL/SQL Developer but I haven't found something similar for SQL Server.

Comment: That tool could be _Microsoft Access_ or _SQL Server Management Studio_.

Comment: @Gustav I asked because I don't know the way so your answer doesn't help. Could be or could not to be. What is that answer? I asked for the way and mentioned that Oracle has similar tool which is capable of doing this.

Comment: Sorry, it was a hint only that came to my mind. Your question is per definition OT here, as SO is all about coding, not tools, neither superuser tasks.

Comment: Sorry, when I saw -1 I really get angry. I clearly asked for a way to copy whole or a part of the MS Excel column and paste it to SQL Server table column. I don't know why -1. How am I supposed to make a question?

Comment: Can't tell who the downvoter is, but - again - SO is for coding questions, not questions about tools or software. There are other Stack fora for these.

Comment: No need to get angry, everyone on this website is trying to help one another and the only way to get help is ask the question. but why not link the SQL server table to your MS Access file and run a pass-through query?

Answer (score 0):

Using ETL tools you can achieve your result. If you need opensource ETL tool then you can go ahead with Pentaho PDI. It's free.